# I am new to react. I want to render a child component using a single state using an onClick event in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

on Click of button the state should be able to render component using statename.map.. Thankyou

```
<div className="container mt-5">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="card pt-3">
          <div className="col-lg-12">
            <h4>Promotional Rates</h4>
            <p>
              Create promotional rate(s)
            </p>
            <button className="btn btn-primary my-3" onClick={???}>
              Add New Promotional Rates
            </button>
    <<<<<<<render child component here using .map>>>>>>>>>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should add a [mcve] showing your component with its state instead of just the JSX you're rendering.

Answer (score 0):

creat a state and u can use whatever method in the js code bellow

```js
import React,{useState} from "react"

const ParentComponent = () =>{
  const [ShowChild,setShowChild]=useState(false)
  
  return(
  <div>
  
    //methode 1
    {ShowChild && ChildComponent}
    // end methode 1
    
    
    //methode 2
    {ShowChild? <ChildComponent /> : ''}
    //end methode 2
    
    
    
    <button onClick={()=>setShowChild(!ShowChild)}>show child Button </button>
  </div>
  )}
  
  
const ChildComponent = () => {
  return(
    <h1>I m a child</h1>
    )
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```